# soft selection vertices on edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is there something like Maya "soft selection" on edit mode? Something like a selection with a gradient value to do modification on a lowpoly mesh?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in blender it is called [Proportional Edit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html?highlight=proportional%20edit).

You just have to enable the tool by pressing <kbd>O</kbd> and then you can adjust its area of influence by using the mouse wheel (or by using <kbd>PgUp</kbd><kbd>PgDown</kbd>) while you perform a tranformation, say, while you are translating a vertice.